# list permission: cannot add a role assignment with empty role definition binding collection

Tags: sharepoint-online, permissions, csom

My scenario : i have stop inheritance from parent on the list and then try the following code-

```
RoleDefinitionBindingCollection collRoleDefinitionBinding = new RoleDefinitionBindingCollection(clientContext);


    collRoleDefinitionBinding.Add(clientContext.Web.RoleDefinitions.GetByType(RoleType.Contributor));



 internalGBC1.RoleAssignments.Add(newgroup, collRoleDefinitionBinding);
```